# Kattis-problem: Building Pyramids - why is this not correct?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to solve this problem here in C#:
https://open.kattis.com/submissions/8340306 (edit: Full question below)

So, in short: Give is a number of bricks. The aim is to figure out, how high I can build a 3D-pyramid with these blocks. The top-level has 1 brick, the 2nd level from the top 9 bricks, the 3rd 25 bricks and so on.

I thought I solved it and with the given example it is correct. It is also correct in all the calculations I did. Yet: From the 5 sample-runs, in it only excepted in 3.

> **Edit - the full question:** When initiating a larger project, like
> building a pyramid, it’s best to think twice. Your task today is to
> write a program that computes how high a pyramid can be built given a
> certain number of blocks of stone.
>
> We assume that the pyramid to be built is compact, i.e. there are no
> cavities inside. Furthermore, we assume it is built according to the
> principle in Figure 1. Each layer is square, with a side length that
> is two less than the one below it. The top layer always consist of a
> single block.[image]
>
> It is fine if you have leftover blocks, as long as you build a
> complete pyramid.
>
> **Input** The first and only line of input contains an integer N
> (1≤N≤100000000), the number of blocks you have available.
>
> **Output** Output a single integer – the maximum height of a pyramid that
> can be built with at least N blocks. [image]

The result of my solution:
[image]

Here is my code - please be gentle, I am just learning :)

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        int bloecke = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int neueBloecke = 1; // Bloecke, die für die neue Ebene benötigt werden
        int sumBloecke = 1; // Blöcke in Summe
        int seitenLaenge = 1; // Seitenlänge der Ebene
        int ebene = 1; // Auf welcher Ebene wir uns aktuell befinden

        while (sumBloecke < bloecke)
        { 
            // Wenn wir weniger als 10 Blöcke haben, brauchen wir gar nicht anzufangen > wir haben 1 Ebene
            if (bloecke < 10)
            {
                ebene = 1;
                break;
            }

            // Andernfalls legen wir los
            seitenLaenge += 2;
            neueBloecke = seitenLaenge * seitenLaenge;
            sumBloecke += neueBloecke;

            if (sumBloecke>=bloecke)
            {
                break;
            } else
            {
                ebene++;
            }

        }

        Console.Write(ebene);

    }
```

Comment: Can you include the challenge in your question? The link only works if you're logged in.

Comment: Hello, the code itself looks ok if I guessed the meaning correctly(I don't know German so I had to string-match the variables ^^). There are two possible issues that I can think of: first - the code might be too slow and the reason for the failures is a timeout and not a wrong answer. Second one could be that the numbers are so large that the **int** type is not large enough - after all, second power grows rather quickly.

Comment: Since the given n is <=100 000 000 it should not be fine with int, but I tried uint and it gives me exactly the same results.

Comment: Can you also include the inputs where it doesn't work? e.g 83 seems to work well with your code.

Comment: `sumBloecke>=bloecke` Should this rather be `>`? (So that `ebene` is incremented if you have an exact matching number of blocks, before leavig the while loop)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've been just messing with this trying to get it to work.  You've complicated it with code that has no real purpose, and now it's confusing.

Your loop has 2 exit conditions when only one is necessary, you have `ebene = 1` in there for no reason, etc.

You are taking the wrong approach.  If you just mess with your code until it works for whatever tests you're applying, then you'll never really be confident that it works for stuff you didn't test.

You need to *prove* to yourself that it is correct.  Try something like this:

- Ensure that, at the top of the loop, the total block count, base area, and edge length are valid for a pyramid size `ebene+1`.  (This is called a loop invariant)
- Exit the loop at the top if the total number of blocks required by that pyramid is more than you have
- Otherwise, increment `ebene` and calculate the variables for the next size, and loop.

If you implement this simple procedure, then you will be confident that the result is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will try this approach!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

````c#
public static void Main()
{
    int availableBlocks = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int newBlocks = 0; // blocks for the new level
    int sumBlocks = 0; // sum of used blocks
    int edgeLength = 0; // blocks on one side of the level
    int level = 0; // which level are we

    while (true)
    {
        // e.g. availableBlocks = 15
        //
        // edge | new | sum | ok? | level
        // 0      0     0     yes   0
        // 1      1     1     yes   1
        // 3      9     10    yes   2
        // 4      16    26    no    -

        // edgeLength increases by 2, except for the first top-level
        if (edgeLength==0)
        {
            edgeLength++;
        } else
        {
            edgeLength += 2;
        }

        newBlocks = edgeLength * edgeLength;
        sumBlocks += newBlocks;

        // Check, if we still have enought blocks
        if (sumBlocks <= availableBlocks)
        {
            level++;
        } else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(level);
            break;
        }
    }
}```
````